# two way to initialize a structure

Tags: c++, constructor, structure

What's the difference between the two ways of creating a structure?

No.1 is right, and No.2 gives the error:

```
reference binding to misaligned address 0x63775f5f00676e6f for type 'const int', which requires 4 byte alignment
```

What's the difference between the two ways of creating a structure?

What did the No.2 do?

Here is my codes.

Thank you.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {     
        if (preorder.size() == 0 || inorder.size() == 0)
            return nullptr;

        // # 1
        // struct TreeNode *RootTree = new TreeNode(preorder.front());

        // # 2
        struct TreeNode RootNode(preorder.front());
        struct TreeNode *RootTree = &RootNode;

        return RootTree;
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with #2 is that you’re returning the address of an object with automatic storage, whose lifetime ends as soon as the function returns.  That is **undefined behavior**.  The standard says that the compiler is entitled to assume you won’t do that, so anything can happen.  If you aren’t getting a warning or error message at compile time, turn on more warnings.  (On gcc or clang, `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` at least.) The address of an object created with `new` is valid, but must be manually deleted.

Either return a `TreeNode` and rely on copy elision to make the code efficient, or return a `std::unique_ptr<TreeNode>` to manage the object’s lifetime for you.